# Training a model by looping through the train_test_split and training without looping

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, data-science

I am new to python and Keras please bear with my question.

1. I recently created a model in Keras, trained it and got the 'mean square error MSE' post prediction. I used the train_test_split function on the data set used.
2. Next I created a while loop with 50 iterations and applied it to the above said model. However I kept the train_test_split function (*random_number not specified) within the loop such that in every iteration I would have a new set of X_train, y_train, X_test and y_test values. I obtained 50 MSE values as output and calculated their 'mean' and 'standard' deviation'. 
   My query was did I do the right thing by placing the train_test_split function within the loop? Does it effect my goal which was to see the different MSE values generated for my data set?
3. If I had placed the train_test_split function outside my while loop and performed the above said activity, wouldn't the X_train, y_train, X_test and y_test values remain the same through out all of my 50 iterations? Wouldn't this cause an over fitting problem to my model?

I would really appreciate your feedback.

My code snippet:

```
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn import metrics
import numpy as np

MSE=np.zeros(50)

for i in range(50):
    predictors_train,predictors_test,target_train,target_test=train_test_split(predictors,target,test_size=0.3)
    model=regression_model()
    model.fit(predictors_train,target_train,validation_data=(predictors_test,target_test),epochs=50,verbose=0)
    model.evaluate(predictors_test,target_test, verbose=0)
    target_predicted=model.predict(predictors_test)
    MSE[i]=metrics.mean_squared_error(target_test, target_predicted)
    print("Test set MSE for {} cycle:{}".format(i+1,MSE[i]))
```

Comment: what's `regression_model()` ?

Comment: Hi good to hear from you. Regression_model() is a function that I defined which contains my Keras network which consists of 2 dense layers with 10 nodes each having adam as the optimized with mse as the loss parameter.

Answer (score 4):

The method you are implementing is named Cross validation, it allow your model to have a better "view" of your data, and reduce the chance that your training data was "too perfect" or "too noisy".

So putting your `train_test_set` in the loop will generate new training batches from your original data, and by meaning the outputs you will have what you want.
If you put the train_test_set outside, the batch of training data will remain the same for all your training loop, resulting in overfitting like you said.

However `train_test_split` is random, so you can have two random batch that are very likely, so this method is not optimal.

A better way is by using the k-fold cross validation :

```py
from sklearn.model_selection import StratifiedKFold

kfold = StratifiedKFold(n_splits=10, shuffle=True, random_state=seed)

MSE = []

for train, test in kfold.split(X, Y):

   model = regression_model()
   model.fit(X[train],y[train],validation_data= (X[test],y[test]),epochs=50,verbose=0)
   model.evaluate(X[test],y[test], verbose=0)
   target_predicted = model.predict(predictors_test)
   MSE.append(metrics.mean_squared_error(y[test], target_predicted))
   print("Test set MSE for {} cycle:{}".format(i+1,MSE[i]))

print("Mean MSE for {}-fold cross validation : {}".format(len(MSE), np.mean(MSE))
```

This method will create 10 folds of your training data and will fit your model using different one at each iteration.

You can have more info here : https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.StratifiedKFold.html

Hope this will help you !

### EDIT FOR PRECISION

Indeed don't use this method on your TEST data, but only on your VALIDATION data !!
You model must never see your TEST data before !

Comment: Thank you for reverting on my query. Your answer nailed it :-)

Answer (score 0):

You don't want to use test set during training at all. You will be tweaking the model to the point where it will start "overfitting" even the test set and your error estimates will be too optimistic.

Yes, if you place `train_test_split` outside of that for loop, your sets will stay the same for the whole training and it can lead to overfitting. That is why you have validation set which is not used for training but for validation, mostly to find out whether your model is ovefitting the train set or not. If it is overfitting, you should solve it by tweaking your model (making it less complex, implementing regularization, early stopping...).

But don't train your model on the same data you use for testing. Training your data on validation set is a different story and it is normally used when implementing K-fold cross validation.

So the general steps to follow are:

1. split your dataset into test set and the "other" set, put the test set away and don't show it to your model until you are ready for final testing => only when you have already trained and tuned your model
2. choose whether you want to implement k-fold cross-validation or not. If not, then split your data into training and validation set and use them throughout the whole training => training set for training and validation set for validating
3. if you want to implement k-fold cross-validation then follow the step 2, measure the error metric that you want to track, pick the other set again, split it into a different training set and validation set, and do the whole training again. Repeat this multiple times to and take average of the error metrics measured during these cycles to get better (average) error estimate
4. tune your model and repeat the steps 2 and 3 until you are happy with the results
5. measure the error of your final model on the test set to see whether it generalizes well

Note that while implementing k-fold cross validation is generally a good idea, this approach might be infeasible for larger neural networks because it can dramatically increase the time it takes to train them. If that is the case, you might want to stick with just one training set and one validation set or set k (in k-folds) to some low number such as 3.

Comment: Thanks for reverting on my query.  I have used the test set to fit my model and the training set to evaluate and predict my model. I am guessing the current state of my model represents a k-fold having k=50 since my train_test_split is inside my while loop.

Comment: Your problem is that you are making the split inside of for loop and the test set is picked randomly. In one iteration some data that was supposed to be used only for testing are instead used for training. This is a very bad idea. Your model should not see any observation from test set until you are done with training and tuning.

Comment: Yes your right every iteration randomly shuffles the data set when creating the training and test sets. This means there is a high chance my model has seen almost all the observations in my entire data set by the time 50 iterations are complete. In this case it means there would be a hig probability of over fitting. However even if I place the split outside the loop I would be causing a over fitting issue because for each iteration the training and testing sets would be fixed?

Comment: This is not necessary overfitting, it is more of a bias => your model is more biased towards the fixed dataset and this can cause overfitting. The way you fight overfitting though is through regularization techniques => placing more constraints on your model, early stopping, choosing less complex model, adding drop layers etc. Not by switching training datasets (unless you are building ensemble of models in which case it is a valid approach).

Comment: Thanks for helping me out :-) I had a thought lingering in my mind. In the current scenario where the train_test_split is within the loop it seems to behave in a similar fashion to that of the K fold cross validation method with K as 50. Am I right in making that assumption?

Comment: Yes, and no. The idea behind k-fold cross-validation is the same. Perform the whole training multiple times, each time using only subset of training set and performing validation on the rest of the training set that wasn't used during training. Difference is that the folds are chosen in a more clever way and that the test set is left untouched during this whole process.

Comment: Thanks again :-) Seems like I was stupid enough to use my entire data set to run a cross validation.